# Nested app.config (web.config) files

Tags: .net, configuration

Is it possible to have two app.config files where one app.config serves as a container for second (nested) app.config file? I would like to reference specific sections of a nested file from the outer one.

Why I need this is because of source control issue. For detailed description see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378953)

Any other solution for the root problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can reference other config files yes, so you can have static stuff in one file, and machine specific stuff in another.

Eg, to put app settings in a seperate file, in a subfolder called "configuration":

```
<appSettings configSource="Configuration\AppSettings.config"/>
```

Then in the AppSettings.config, just include the appSettings tag as normal:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="somekey" value="someValue" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, the answer is "Yes".  See the section on "Using External Configuration Files" in this article.  It's not ***nesting*** the files as your title would imply, but based on the question text...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx