# Breaking up web.config file system.webServer element

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I am trying to break a large `web.config` file into smaller parts. This has been covered a few times on different stack overflow questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380240/nested-app-config-web-config-files) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480538/use-xml-includes-or-config-references-in-app-config-to-include-other-config-files)) which recommend using the `configSource` or `file` attributes.

The problem is this does not work for the `system.webServer` section used to configure IIS 7 in integrated mode. This is particularly bad for `web.config` files that have IIS Rewrite rules which tend to bloat the files.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just leave system.webbServer within the web.config and break out what you can?  (I'm assuming that's not an option...but I figured I'd ask why you aren't doing that.)

Comment: It it content within the system.webServer that I am trying to break up. For our scenario we have sections of it that we would like to change and manage differently but we can leave the majority of web.config intact.